# Phonejs binding data

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, phonejs

I'm testing phonejs, so I downloaded latest version from website and inside demo folder there is RealtoApp example. I'm looking inside it and I'm a bit confused.

Inside data folder there is one javascript file called **sampleData.js**, it defines in `RealtorApp.data.SampleData = { ... }` all **static** information to process , is there an easy way to binding remotely this information instead of this static data ??
The most part of this is **javascript, jquery and knockout** so I'm sure you are the bests in that.

I swear I have looked all tutorials and I just find new DevExpress.data.Datasource object with the load function and getJson method, I think that it's the way but it would be great to know how to merge this in the RealtoApp demo.

Some help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static data (RealtorApp.data.SampleData) is used by data access layer defined in **dataLayer.js**

The dataLayer is a bunch of functions that emulates asynchronous data access.
So you can just implement them with $.getJSON or any other async call to the server.
Just replace setTimeout with your async call, e.g.

```
function getPropertiesByCoordinates(latitude, longitude) {
    var result = $.Deferred();

    $.getJSON("your url", function(data) {
        var properties = [];
        $.each(data, function(_, value) {
            properties.push(new RealtorApp.data.PropertyViewModel(value));
        });
        result.resolve(data);
    });

    // INSTEAD OF 
    //setTimeout(function() {
    //    var properties = [];
    //    $.each(RealtorApp.data.SampleData, function(_, value) {
    //        properties.push(new RealtorApp.data.PropertyViewModel(value));
    //    });
    //    result.resolve(properties);
    //}, TIMEOUT);

    return result.promise();
}
```

If you wish to find an example how to work with real remote service look at Skate Shop Demo
https://www.devexpress.com/Products/HTML-JS/demos.xml#!demo=devextreme-skate-demo

Actually, PhoneJS has strong data layer (from static js arrays to rest services).
Check out following links
http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Layer?version=13_2#Data_Layer
http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Source_Examples?version=13_2#Data_Source_Examples

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works like a champ !